# .Net, XmlDSigEx: CngKey.import using public key from X509Certificate2

Tags: .net, x509certificate, cng

I'm trying to validate XML Signatures that have been signed with ECDsa algorithms. I'm basing my work on the XmlDSigEx library, which I have to modify slightly to fit my needs. **My present problem is related to getting the public key from the certificate and use it as a CngKey.** I used:

```
// var cert = X509Certificate2 ...
var key = CngKey.Import(cert.GetPublicKey(), CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
```

which throws "The parameter is not correct". I could not find any information which format of the public key is expected to be passed in as the key. I kindly ask therefore for help on this matter: **How do I pass the public key stored in the X509Certificate to the CngKey?**

TIA,
Alois

PS: I considered to use BouncyCastle to extract the public key. I tried BC's

```
X509Certificate.CertificateStructure.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.GetEncoded()
```

as well as

```
X509Certificate.CertificateStructure.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKeyData.GetBytes()
```

to pass the key to the CngKey; however the same error occures.

Answer (score 0):

I have been battling the same type of issue but using BouncyCastle for C# and trying to import the keys into CngKey. ECDsaCng supports RFC4050 XML format for public key import. I have managed to import keys generated using BouncyCastle using the code below and verify hashes with ECDsaCng which were produced with BouncyCastle.

```
//Specify which curve we are using   
string theCurveName = "prime256v1";

X509Certificate2 x509cert = null; //get your x509 certificate here...

//BouncyCastle publickey creation from certificate publickey
var namedCurve = X962NamedCurves.GetByName(theCurveName);

ECPublicKeyParameters publickey = new ECPublicKeyParameters("ECDSA",
    namedCurve.Curve.DecodePoint(x509cert.GetPublicKey()), // Q
    X962NamedCurves.GetOid(theCurveName));

//now we have the public key in bouncy castle
//we can create the xml to import to CngKey            
//Prime256v1 = 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7

var xmlImport = @"<ECDSAKeyValue xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#'>
  <DomainParameters>
    <NamedCurve URN='urn:oid:" + X962NamedCurves.GetOid(theCurveName).Id + @"' />
  </DomainParameters>
  <PublicKey>
    <X Value='" + publickey.Q.X.ToBigInteger().ToString() + @"' xsi:type='PrimeFieldElemType' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' />
    <Y Value='" + publickey.Q.Y.ToBigInteger().ToString() + @"' xsi:type='PrimeFieldElemType' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' />
  </PublicKey>
</ECDSAKeyValue>";

var eccImporter = new ECDsaCng();
eccImporter.FromXmlString(xmlImport, ECKeyXmlFormat.Rfc4050);


//prep bouncy castle signature to single array
var sig0 = sig[0].ToByteArrayUnsigned();
var sig1 = sig[1].ToByteArrayUnsigned();   
byte[] newSig = new byte[sig0.Length + sig1.Length];
sig0.CopyTo(newSig, 0);
sig1.CopyTo(newSig, sig0.Length);

var isok = eccImporter.VerifyHash(manualhash, newSig);
```